# URL showing unnecessary post types in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

My website, let's call it example.com, has a few Post Types:

```
 - Post (the default post type) with the slug 'blog'
 - Cases with the slug 'cases'
 - Klanten with the slug 'klanten' (Dutch word for clients)
```

When I go to the blog page, the url shows like this:

```
example.com/blog/
```

And when I then navigate to a blog post, it shows this:

```
example.com/blog/blog-title/
```

This is also good.

---

But now the problem. When I go the the cases page, the URL shows like this:

```
example.com/cases/
```

This is fine, but when I select a case, the URL shows like this:

```
example.com/blog/cases/case-title/
```

Ofcourse, I want this URL to be:

```
example.com/cases/case-title/
```

Comment: Looks like you have either provide some coding details or ask at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wordpress.stackexchange.com? Damn, that's like an heaven to me atm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call register_post_type() param 'rewrite' with additional argument 'with_front' => false

> From Codex documentation:
>   'with_front' => bool Should the permalink structure be prepended with
>   the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then
>   your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to
>   true

```
$args = array(
    /*other args*/
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cases', 'with_front' => false),
    /*other args*/
);
register_post_type( 'cases', $args );
```